# Azure function deployment of single Python script and process of installation of requirements.txt in Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-yaml, requirements.txt

I am completely new to Azure. I recently deployed my Python Script on Azure Functions (HTTP). It worked completely fine for me. The problem I faced is when my Python script needed some packages to be installed like (pandas, psycopy2). Although I put them in requirements.txt file. And after deployment requirements.txt is stored in root directory (same as of host.json) but I am getting import error.
I don't really know how to install these packages in azure function.
Any help would be really really appreciated.

I tried deploying python script using multiple techniques but none of them worked for me, I just have one python script and I need to install requirement.txt file in azure function.
Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed a package (**'requests'**) and ran http trigger function locally by creating a new function app with `python3.9`. I was able to deploy it to Azure and triggered successfully without any error.

***Note***: *Make sure that while adding any package in* `requirements.txt` *file, install package in the project directory folder itself by giving:*

```
pip install  --target="<local project directory path>/.python_packages/lib/site-packages"  -r requirements.txt
```

*Here, I've taken* `requests == 2.19.1` *latest version package and imported in* `init.py`

***requirements.txt:***

```
azure-functions
requests==2.19.1
```

***While executing locally, I received the desired outcome***:-

[image]

***Deployed to Azure:***

[image]

**`requirements.txt` *file after deploying it to Azure***:

[image]

***Received "200 Ok" response after test/run***:

[image]

You can check here [Refer MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi,application-level&pivots=python-mode-configuration#package-management)